# Correct Way to Reassign Workflow Tasks in Visual Studio WF

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, tasks

What is the correct way to programmatically reassign a task to another individual in a SharePoint 2010 custom workflow? We do not want to simply change the person to whom the task is assigned although that would be acceptable if another way cannot be found. We'd like to create a new task assigned to a different individual and then complete the old task.

We have seen this SharePoint SE question/answer which helped us generate a new task but is just assigning the new task to the original task's assigned to. Ultimately the issue is so crazy I believe we fundamentally do not understand how we should be approaching the problem. If someone could assist us on how this should be accomplished, I would be very thankful.

We are attempting to perform the reassignment via JavaScript Object Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to accomplish this is by changing the AssignedTo field in the task list, although I know this isn't the preferred method.
To do this I had the JavaScript update the task list with two fields I created called "Approval" and "ReassignedTo".  In the Approval Field I placed the value "reassigned" and in the ReassignedTo field was the value of the user the task is being reassigned to.

Once those values are changed, the "On_TaskChanged" method of my Workflow is activated.  In this method I inserted the following code:

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(OrigWorkflowProperties.WebUrl.ToString()))
    {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
            try
               {
                    SPUser Approver = OrigWorkflowProperties.Web.AllUsers[e.Identity];
                    int tid = TaskPropertiesAfter.TaskItemId;
                    SPListItem currentTaskItem = OrigWorkflowProperties.TaskList.GetItemById(tid);
                    TaskApproval = (currentTaskItem["Approval"].ToString());
                    if (TaskApproval.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        OrigWorkflowProperties.LogComment(TaskApproval, "The item was " + TaskApproval + " by " + Approver.Name);
                        if (TaskApproval == "Reassigned")
                        {
                            Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
                            ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
                            ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] = currentTaskItem["ReassignedTo"];
                            ht["ReassignedTo"] = null;
                            ht["Approval"] = string.Empty;

                            SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(currentTaskItem, ht, true);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            //perform actions if item is not reassigned
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("_taskchanged_", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

This will set the AssignedTo field in the TaskList accordingly, and then clear the ReassignedTo and Approval Fields so that the next time the task is changed, we don't reassign the task undesirably a 2nd time.

The code `currentTaskItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;` keeps the task from being locked by the workflow on future changes to the task, and is necessary.

If there is a better way, then I would also be interested

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint SE and thanks for the answer!

Comment: SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(currentTaskItem, ht, true); The workflow always locked at here. Any idea why? I have include this code ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1; as well